# Context initialization failed : Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a probleme when I deploy my webapp into Tomcat 7.

```
ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mybeanName' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.105/wtpwebapps/myWebApp/WEB-INF/lib/module-5.1.12.jar!/module-beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mybeanname2' while setting bean property 'mybeanname2'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mybeanname2' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.105/wtpwebapps/myWebApp/WEB-INF/lib/module-5.1.12.jar!/module-beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mybeanName3' while setting bean property 'property'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mybeanName3' defined in file [D:\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.105\wtpwebapps\myWebApp\WEB-INF\classes\name-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Impossible de créer l'instance de la ressource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5653)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In module-beans.xml:

```html
<bean id="mybeanName" class="pathofclass">
        <property name="mybeanname2" ref="mybeanname2" />
        <property name="mailMessageFabrique" ref="mailMessageFabrique"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mybeanname2" class="pathofclass">
        <property name="session" ref="mybeanName3" />
</bean>
```

In name-context.xml:

```html
<bean id="mybeanName3" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/resource" />
</bean>
```

Any ideas?
in the file name-context.xml the bean is mybeanName3
thanks for understanding

Comment: have you included the name-context.xml to your application context? Could u share the snippet where you initialize the application context? also please check if its mybeamName3 or mybeanName3

Comment: yes my name-context.xml is included on my application context.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reference to `Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mybeamName3'` in the error message.

Looks like a typo (bea**m**) when referencing this bean.

Comment: Did this fix your problem?